# Error: st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE

Tags: r, geometry, spatial, srid

I am trying to execute following code to get nearest distance:

```
df1   <- fread("df1.csv")

df2<- fread("df2.csv")

#converting geometry column data in df1 from wkb to multilinestring:
df1$geometry <- sf::st_as_sfc(structure(as.list(df1$geometry), class = "WKB"), EWKB=TRUE)

#Gelocate:

MSF  <- st_as_sf(df2, coords = c("Longitude","Latitude"))%>% sf::st_set_crs(4326)
MSF  <- MSF %>% dplyr::mutate(nearest_geometry = df1[st_nearest_feature(geometry, df1), ]$geometry)
```

---

But it gives the following error:

```
Error in `stopifnot()`:
! Problem while computing `nearest_geometry = wkb_data[st_nearest_feature(geometry, wkb_data),
  ]$geometry`.
Caused by error:
! st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE
```

---

For your information, the geometry column data in df1 was initially like:

```
df1$geometry :"0105000020E61000002100000001020000000D0000002EBF61F61BB355C09CE8FB1AD30E424034E6D51712B355C04815A8F5EA0E............"
then I converted wkb format to multilinestring:
df1$geometry:"list(c(-122.396182945493, -122.396169444649, -122.396161..."
```

Comment: What's the crs of df1?

Comment: @Maël How should I check that?
Also, with some examples online I tried the following as well:
df1$geometry <- sf::st_set_crs(df1$geometry,4326)
But still same error.

Comment: you can look at the output of st_crs

Comment: Also, try to provide reproducible data, otherwise it's difficult to answer.

Comment: It gives:
> st_crs(df1)
Coordinate Reference System: NA

Comment: Then you should do df1 %>% st_as_sf(., crs = 4326)

Comment: same error @Maël